# traversing from variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I was trying to traverse from variable to my required destination, but, i could not. Am trying to get the 'th' width in a 'table'. The below code is not working. Am I really making sense? Please. If not, **how I can traverse from variable to my required point**. Any help please?

```
var tabNamecurr = $("table#refparts");

alert($(tabNamecurr + "thead tr th").eq(5).width());
```

Also, I have tried this below code and it is working as expected.

```
alert($(tabNamecurr).find("thead tr th").eq(5).width());
```

But, my intention is I **need to traverse from variable**, How i can achieve that?

Comment: Try `tabNamecurr.find("thead tr th").eq(5).width()`! Since `tabNamecurr` is an object so you don't have to wrap it again in `$`

Comment: @DhavalMarthak, Kindly read my question clearly once again.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method should have worked, but I don't know why it isn't and as @DhavalMarthak said without `$` too works since you already have an object of your table!

```
var tabNamecurr = $("table#refparts");
alert(tabNamecurr.find("thead tr th").eq(5).width());
```

I suggest you to check for any console errors or whether you have 6 `th's` in your table as `eq(5)` refers `6th` header!!

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/27mzb2ph/1/)**